# Send Data to the server when press the button

Tags: javascript

I have a code below which makes a connection with the server and sends the commands to the server when it is called:

```
  <script>

    var socket = new Xcomm('192.168.118.143:8080');
    socket.on('ready', function (err, data)
    {

    document.getElementById('name').addEventListener("click", function(){ 

  var userinfo = {
                'USERNAME': document.getElementById('name').value,
            };

            socket.xreq('USERLOGIN', [
                { 'USERDATA': userinfo }
            ], function (err, data) {
                if (!err)
                    console.log("Response from xcomm:", data);
                else
                    console.log("ERROR:", err, "with response from xcomm:", data);
            })
            });

 });
```

the problem now is that when I call put any data in the textbox in the index.html and press button it sends empty data instead what I put there.

```
<body>
    <div id="error-container"></div>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your name!">
    <button type="button" name="button" >
        Let me chat!
    </button>
</body>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to `socket.on` is called when the connection is ready.

You aren't using a function *declaration*. You aren't creating a variable called `setUsername` that you can access later.

---

Remove the `onclick` attribute. They are generally more trouble then they are worth and are rather unhelpful here.

Change the function you pass to `socket.on` to one which finds the button in the DOM (e.g. with `document.querySelector`) and then using `addEventListener` to attach a (click) event handler to it.

Do the work you are currently doing in `setUsername` inside that event handler instead (i.e. when the button is clicked).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried like you said but now it sends an empty data when I press the button. I edited my first post how I did a change.